# jQuery AJAX not firing in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, coldfusion, cfc

I have a piece of code.  Conceptually, I understand what's going on, but I don't understand why it's not working:

```
function Update(id,day,sid)
{   
var sendMail;
form = $('Update_Appointment_'+day);

if($(id + '_Student_Appointment_' + sid) != null && $(id + '_Student_Appointment_' + sid).value != '')
    $('Delete_Student_Appointment').value=$(id + '_Student_Appointment_' + sid).value;
else
    $('Delete_Student_Appointment').value='';

form.action = 'appointment_popup.cfm?type=online&range_'+day+'=' + $F('Week_Select');
Set_ID(id,day,sid);

$q.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: 'cfc/email_appointment.cfc',
    data: {
        'method' : 'email_update',
        'Appointment_ID': id,
        'Consultant_ID': $q('[name="'+id+'_Consultant"]').val()
    },
    sucess: function(){
        alert('Yay!');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Boo!');
    },
    complete: function(){
        alert('Complete!');
    }       
}); 
return sendMail;
```

}

Originally, this piece of code was supposed to do an update and submit a form, which works.  I added a piece where, after the update, it would fire an AJAX call to a CFC and that CFC will check to see what the update was and email changes if needed.

Now, my issue is this: I can get the code to work in the console, if I call the function like `Update(987, foo, 123456)`.  I can also see the function being completed in Chrome's Network tab, with a status code of 200.  On both options, the "Complete!" alert box fires as well.

Here are the differences from the browser calling the function and calling the function from the console:
The console will have a preview and response data whereas the browser will say "This request has no preview available" and "This request has no response data available."
The console will send the email it's supposed to, but the browser will not.

I feel like I'm not understanding a fundamental thing about AJAX calls, but I don't know what it would be.  I only know that the AJAX call has to be set to `async: false` because `async: true` doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using `$`, `$q`, and `$F` throughout your code? are those differing versions of jQuery? Also, `async: true` vs `async: false` won't make your ajax call "not work", it'l make your logic around the ajax call not work.

Comment: What happens when you set `async: true`? `Doesn't work` is not too helpful.

Comment: @KevinB - Yes, $q and $F are different versions of jQuery. $ was co-opted for some function (I think it was to put the DOM in an array). I have no idea why, but it was made around 2007, so it might have been someone's bright idea.

Comment: @KarlAnderson - setting `async: true` will have red text in Chrome's network tabe with status being '(canceled)' and the alerts 'Boo' and 'Complete' popping up.  Those are expected.

Comment: @Chester - so you expect failure when you call it asynchronously, but do not expect failure when you call it synchronously? I am confused.

Comment: @KarlAnderson - I'm saying that if it's set to `async: true`, the alert button 'Boo' pops up.  That makes sense, since the call has failed.  But I don't want it to fail.  If I set it to `async: false` the alert button 'Boo' does NOT pop up.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that your ajax call isn't working it that it is not reporting back the way **you** want it to.

`async : false` is telling ajax to wait and "see" what the result is

`async: true` basically means fire off the ajax call and keep moving through the code without waiting for the response.